# How to add tap action on notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to add a tap action (exit (finish)) to a notification.
I'm making a simple app with several classes, and I want them all finished when I tap the notification.
Here is my notification code:

```
mMN = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification n = new Notification();
        n.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        n.tickerText = "Tap this notification to exit";
        n.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Intent nid = new Intent(MainActivity.this, stopservice.class);
        PendingIntent ci = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, nid,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        CharSequence ct = "TAP";
        CharSequence tt = "Tap here to exit";
        n.setLatestEventInfo(this,ct,tt,ci);
        mMN.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, n);
```

I'm making a reference to `stopservice class` (where it is my stop service code) on `Intent nid`, but I'm not quite sure if it's a correct reference.

hope that my question is clear.

Comment: Could you clarify a little more about what you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to achieve something like a `onClickListener` on a Notification? If so, there isn't necessarily a direct way of doing that. You will need to create an `Intent` that completes your actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using a notification builder:

```
mMN = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);        

Intent nid = new Intent(MainActivity.this, stopservice.class);
// If you were starting a service, you wouldn't using getActivity() here
PendingIntent ci = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, NOTIFICATION_ID, nid, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setContentTitle("TAP")
        .setContentText("Tap here to exit")
        .setTicker("Tap this notification to exit")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentIntent(ci)
        .setAutoCancel(true); // auto cancel means the notification will remove itself when pressed

mMN.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.getNotification());
```

Your code is set to launch the Activity "stopservice" (which technically should be "StopService" with naming conventions), are you sure that class is an Activity?

Also, **make sure** your Activity is registered in your app's manifest:

```
<activity android:name="[package-name].stopservice" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```